# Rolling Figures Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, random, timer, numbers

I am trying to make a random number generator that by default has 000 (Depending on the range). when a button is pushed the 000 spin though 0 to 9 and after 3 seconds the first number stops and then half a second alter the next one stops and so on.

Is there anything in Java Swing that will allow me to do this?

Comment: would I be able to get an example of how I would use one? the only way I could think of is a continuous loop till it reaches a certain number then stops.

Comment: You can find many examples by simply searching this site.

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+timer+imageicon) and also [my examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+timer+imageicon)

Comment: Thanks ill read through these and see if I can implement any of them